# Как заменить изображение без изменений HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет! Я полный нуб в JS и прошу помощи. Гуглил много, но видимо моих знаний не хватает. Суть такая. Есть изображение, добавленное в html и у него нет `id` и только `class`. Как я могу с помощью JS или jQuery заменить картинку
Вот фрагмент html:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px">
<img width="50" class="user-profile-image user-default-profile-image " src="img/default_profile_50.png"></div>
```

Пытался присвоить `id` с помощью:

```
function myFoo1(){document.getElementsByClassName("user-default-profile-image")[0].id = "defimage"; }
```

и заменять:

```
$('#defimage').attr('src', '/fileservice/file/download/a/233337/sc/494/h/c803022e0f37921830b75a0d243e73e0.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

`element.querySelector();` - найдет первый попавшийся элемент.

```js
const image = document.querySelector('.image');

image.setAttribute('src', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale');
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="#"> <!-- will be found -->
<img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="#"> <!-- will not be found -->
```

если картинок несколько

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.image');

images.forEach((image) => {
  image.setAttribute('src', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale');
});
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="#"> <!-- will be found -->
<img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="#"> <!-- will be found -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Представим ситуацию, что у нас есть сайт, на котором есть всё, а нам нужна лишь картинка.
Первое, что я бы советовал сделать, это найти её родителя, который имеет идентификатор и чем уникальнее, тем лучше.

Допустим мы нашли и это выглядит так:

```html
<!-- ... Где-то в недрах кода -->
<div id="content">
  <h3>Как выглядит жираф</h3>
  <img width="250" border="1" src="//i.imgur.com/GClq9wY.png">
  <div>Жираф</div>
</div>
<!-- ... Где-то в недрах кода -->
```

Нам нужно обратиться к этому родителю по идентификатору, потом найти в нём все картинки, а после чего уже по порядковому номеру (индексу) найти именно нашу.

```js
document // Обратимся к документу
  .getElementById('content') // Потому к родителю
  .getElementsByTagName('img')[0] // Возмём в нём первый по счёту элемент IMG
  .src = '//i.imgur.com/vsDvm4a.png' // И изменим в нём ссылку на нужную.
```

```html
<!-- ... Где-то в недрах кода -->
<div id="content">
  <h3>Как выглядит жираф</h3>
  <img width="250" border="1" src="//i.imgur.com/GClq9wY.png">
  <div>Жираф</div>
</div>
<!-- ... Где-то в недрах кода -->
```

Если наша картинка будет не первой, а допустим десятой, то нам нужно указать `.getElementsByTagName('img')[9]` (9, потому что отсчёт с нуля).

---

В **jQuery** запись будет проще:

```js
$('#content img') // Ищем IMG в родителе
  .eq(0) // Берём первую картинку 
  .attr('src', '//i.imgur.com/vsDvm4a.png'); // Меняем значение атрибута SRC на своё
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- ... Где-то в недрах кода -->
<div id="content">
  <h3>Как выглядит жираф</h3>
  <img width="250" border="1" src="//i.imgur.com/GClq9wY.png">
  <div>Жираф</div>
</div>
<!-- ... Где-то в недрах кода -->
```